# Webscraping a drop down menu. Need the selected value and its results

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I don't have a lot of experience webscraping, I can do basics so this is a little over my head. The end result I would like is a list of farmers with the markets they sell at. There's a table where you select a farmer and the markets show up below. You can select other things, but I'm only interested in selecting and saving each farmer and saving their markets.

https://www.grownyc.org/greenmarket/ourmarkets

I have tried BS4 and have looked at Selenium but I don't know where to go next. I have inspected the html and know where everything is but I don't know how to get the results I need. I can get all the option values for farmers and markets separately, but I can't generate anything that shows which values go together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use their Ajax API to load the data. For example:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://www.grownyc.org/greenmarket.php"

payload = {
    "nid": "",
    "address": "",
    "borough": "",
    "farmer": "Angel Family Farm",
    "daysopen": "",
    "ebt": "false",
    "textile": "false",
    "compost": "false",
    "battery": "false",
    "youthmarket": "false",
}


data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

df = pd.DataFrame(data["sites"])
print(df[["name", "timesopen", "street"]])
```

Prints:

```
                              name          timesopen                street
0               Corona Greenmarket  8:00 am - 3:00 pm  103-28 Roosevelt Ave
1  4th Ave Sunset Park Greenmarket  8:00 am - 3:00 pm     4th Ave & 59th St
2  7th Ave Sunset Park Greenmarket          8am - 3pm
```

Comment: Thank you!  How do you suggest getting results for all the farmers? A loop? python? or is there something that works with ajax or json.

Comment: @analyze_this I suggest a loop. You first get names of all farmers and then loop over this list to get all data.

Comment: I have the farmers so should be able to do that, thanks!